# Determining confidence for individuals' performance

Tags: binary-data, error, confidence-interval

Apologies if this is ridiculously basic - I have searched the site but my vocabulary is probably too limited to be successful.

I have a group of individuals performing a task with a boolean outcome - success or failure. Each individual performs the task a different number of times.

I'm asked to report on the success rate of individuals, but my intuition is that I should be able to identify a confidence interval, especially since some individuals have performed the task many fewer times than others.

Some concrete numbers, since I'm probably being unclear:

Overall there have been 688 attempts with 175 successes, a 25.4% success rate.

Individual 1 has made 112 attempts with 31 successes, a 27.7% rate.
Individual 2 has made 14 attempts with 3 successes, a 21.4% rate.

It seems obvious to me that I'm much less confident in the true success rate for Individual 2 than I am Individual 1, but I don't know how to measure that, or even what the name of this kind of task is (repeated binary? something like that?)

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

The very first equation should be roughly what you need,